# Number guessing game in Kotlin

Tags: beginner, number-guessing-game, kotlin

Is this code missing any "Kotlinisms"?

I've just started learning Kotlin so I'm not yet familiar with the Kotlin way of doing things.

The program will guess a number you are thinking of.

```
package challenges.difficult

/**
 * Created by jbarnes on 04/06/2016.
 * Challenge: https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/pii6j/difficult_challenge_1/
 */

fun main(args:Array<String>) {
    Guesser();
}

class Guesser(range:IntRange) {

    private var range = range;
    private var upperLimit:Int = range.last;
    private var lowerLimit:Int = range.first;
    private var turnCount:Int = 0;
    private var lastGuess:Int = 0;
    private var lastResponse:Response = Response.UNKNOWN;

    constructor():this(1..100)

    init {
        printIntro();
        while (lastResponse != Response.CORRECT) {
            lastResponse = presentNextGuess();
            turnCount++;
            if (lastResponse == Response.CORRECT) {
                println("I guessed your number in $turnCount turns.");
            }
            if (lastResponse == Response.UNKNOWN) {
                println("I'm sorry, I didn't understand that.");
            }
        }

    }

    fun calcNextGuess():Int {
        var roundingFactor = 0;
        if (lastResponse == Response.HIGHER) {
            lowerLimit = lastGuess;
            roundingFactor = 1; //compensates for rounding down
        } else if (lastResponse == Response.LOWER) {
            upperLimit = lastGuess;
        }
        return (lowerLimit + ((upperLimit - lowerLimit) / 2)) + roundingFactor;
    }

    fun presentNextGuess():Response {
        val nextGuess = calcNextGuess();
        println("Is your number $nextGuess?");
        val response = readLine();
        lastGuess = nextGuess;
        return parseResponse(response);
    }

    fun parseResponse(response:String?):Response {
        if (response == null) {
            return Response.UNKNOWN;
        } else if (response.equals("higher", true) || response.equals("h", true)) {
            return Response.HIGHER;
        } else if (response.equals("lower", true) || response.equals("l", true)) {
            return Response.LOWER;
        } else if (response.equals("yes", true) || response.equals("y", true)) {
            return Response.CORRECT;
        } else {
            return Response.UNKNOWN;
        }
    }


    fun printIntro() {
        println("Think of a number between 1 and 100. I am going to try and guess it.");
        println("If i guess correctly respond with 'yes' (or 'y')");
        println("Otherwise respond to with either 'higher' (or 'h') or 'lower' (or 'l')");
        println("Okay, here we go...");
    }

    enum class Response {
        HIGHER, LOWER, CORRECT, UNKNOWN
    }
}
```

https://github.com/JNBarnes/LearningKotlin/blob/master/src/challenges/difficult/GuessingGame.kt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Semi-colons are **optional** so, avoid them if possible.
- Use **type inference** when possible. For example:

  ```
  val aInteger = 1 // Int is inferred by the compiler as the type of `aInteger`

  val aListOfInt = listOf(1, 2) // List<Int> is inferred by the compiler as the type of `aListOfInt`
  ```
- Constructors, in particular primary constructor, are very powerful. For example: `class Guesser(val range: IntRange = 1..100)` is equivalent to:

  ```
  class Guesser(range: IntRange) {
    val range = range

    constructor(): this(1..100)
  }
  ```
- `val` is for **read-only** properties. If you need to **re-assign** a property, use `var` instead.
- The use of `raw string`s with the `trimMargin()` member function is preferable over multiple `println` invocations.
- The `when expression` is similar to the more traditional `switch`. You can learn more about it [here](http://Some%20suggestions:%20%20-%20Semi-colons%20are%20optional%20so,%20avoid%20them%20if%20posible.%20%20-%20Use%20type%20inference%20when%20posible.%20For%20example:%20%20%20%20%20%20val%20aInteger%20=%201%20//%20Int%20is%20inferred%20by%20the%20compiler%20as%20the%20type%20of%20%60aInteger%60%20%20%20%20%20%20val%20aListOfInt%20=%20listOf(1,%202)%20//%20List%3CInt%3E%20is%20inferred%20by%20the%20compiler%20as%20the%20type%20of%20%60aListOfInt%60%20%20-%20Constructors,%20in%20particular%20primary%20constructor,%20are%20very%20powerful.%20For%20example:%20%60class%20Guesser(val%20range:%20IntRange%20=%201..100)%60%20is%20equivalent%20to:%20%20%20%20%20%20class%20Guesser(range:%20IntRange)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20val%20range%20=%20range%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor():%20%20this(1..100)%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20-%20%60val%60%20is%20for%20read-only%20properties.%20If%20you%20need%20to%20re-assign%20a%20property,%20use%20%60var%60%20instead.%20%20-%20The%20use%20of%20%60raw%20string%60s%20with%20the%20%60trimMargin()%60%20member%20function%20is%20preferable%20over%20multiple%20%60println%60%20invocations.%20%20-%20The%20%60when%20expression%60%20is%20similar%20to%20the%20more%20traditional%20%60switch%60.%20You%20can%20learn%20more%20about%20it%20here.%20%20%20This%20is%20the%20whole%20thing:%20%20%20%20%20%20class%20Guesser(val%20range:%20IntRange%20=%201..100)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20var%20upperLimit%20=%20range.last%20%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20var%20lowerLimit%20=%20range.first%20%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20var%20turnCount%20=%200%20%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20var%20lastGuess%20=%200%20%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20var%20lastResponse%20=%20Response.UNKNOWN%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20init%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20printIntro()%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20while%20(lastResponse%20!=%20Response.CORRECT)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20lastResponse%20=%20presentNextGuess()%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20turnCount++%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20when%20(lastResponse)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Response.CORRECT%20-%3E%20println(%22I%20guessed%20your%20number%20in%20$turnCount%20turns.%22)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Response.UNKNOWN%20-%3E%20println(%22I'm%20sorry,%20I%20didn't%20understand%20that.%22)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%20-%3E%20%7B%7D%20//%20Must%20be%20exhaustive.%20Do%20nothing%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fun%20calcNextGuess():%20Int%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20roundingFactor%20=%200%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20when%20(lastResponse)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Response.HIGHER%20-%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20lowerLimit%20=%20lastGuess%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20roundingFactor%20=%201%20//compensates%20for%20rounding%20down%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Response.LOWER%20-%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20upperLimit%20=%20lastGuess%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%20-%3E%20assert(false)%20//%20Must%20be%20exhaustive.%20Assume%20error%20if%20this%20is%20reached%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(lowerLimit%20+%20((upperLimit%20-%20lowerLimit)%20/%202))%20+%20roundingFactor%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fun%20presentNextGuess():%20Response%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20val%20nextGuess%20=%20calcNextGuess()%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println(%22Is%20your%20number%20$nextGuess?%22)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20val%20response%20=%20readLine()%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20lastGuess%20=%20nextGuess%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20parseResponse(response)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fun%20parseResponse(response:%20String?):%20Response%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(response%20==%20null)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Response.UNKNOWN%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(response.equals(%22higher%22,%20true)%20%7C%7C%20response.equals(%22h%22,%20true))%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Response.HIGHER%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(response.equals(%22lower%22,%20true)%20%7C%7C%20response.equals(%22l%22,%20true))%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Response.LOWER%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(response.equals(%22yes%22,%20true)%20%7C%7C%20response.equals(%22y%22,%20true))%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Response.CORRECT%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Response.UNKNOWN%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fun%20printIntro()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println(%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%22%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7CThink%20of%20a%20number%20between%201%20and%20100.%20I%20am%20going%20to%20try%20and%20guess%20it.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7CIf%20i%20guess%20correctly%20respond%20with%20'yes'%20(or%20'y')%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7COtherwise%20respond%20to%20with%20either%20'higher'%20(or%20'h')%20or%20'lower'%20(or%20'l')%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7COkay,%20here%20we%20go...%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%22%22.trimMargin()%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enum%20class%20Response%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20HIGHER,%20LOWER,%20CORRECT,%20UNKNOWN%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20fun%20main(args:Array%3CString%3E)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Guesser()%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20Note:%20I'm%20also%20learning%20the%20language%20and%20I%20could%20be%20wrong%20with%20some%20things%20so,%20the%20above%20code%20can%20be%20improved%20and%20is%20not%20free%20of%20mistakes%20and%20non-idiomatic%20constructs.).

This is the whole thing:

```
class Guesser(val range: IntRange = 1..100) {
  private var upperLimit = range.last
  private var lowerLimit = range.first
  private var turnCount = 0
  private var lastGuess = 0
  private var lastResponse = Response.UNKNOWN

  init {
    printIntro()

    while (lastResponse != Response.CORRECT) {
      lastResponse = presentNextGuess()
      turnCount++

      when (lastResponse) {
        Response.CORRECT -> println("I guessed your number in $turnCount turns.")
        Response.UNKNOWN -> println("I'm sorry, I didn't understand that.")
      }
    }
  }

  fun calcNextGuess(): Int {
    var roundingFactor = 0

    when (lastResponse) {
      Response.HIGHER -> {
        lowerLimit = lastGuess
        roundingFactor = 1 //compensates for rounding down
      }
      Response.LOWER -> {
        upperLimit = lastGuess
      }
      else -> assert(false) // Assume error if this is reached
    }

    return (lowerLimit + ((upperLimit - lowerLimit) / 2)) + roundingFactor
  }

  fun presentNextGuess(): Response {
    val nextGuess = calcNextGuess()

    println("Is your number $nextGuess?")

    val response = readLine()

    lastGuess = nextGuess

    return parseResponse(response)
  }

  fun parseResponse(response: String?) = when (response?.toLowerCase()) {
    null -> Response.UNKNOWN
    "higher", "h" -> Response.HIGHER
    "lower", "l" -> Response.LOWER
    "yes", "y" -> Response.CORRECT
    else -> Response.UNKNOWN
  }

  fun printIntro() {
    println(
      """
        Think of a number between 1 and 100. I am going to try and guess it.
        If i guess correctly respond with 'yes' (or 'y')
        Otherwise respond to with either 'higher' (or 'h') or 'lower' (or 'l')
        Okay, here we go...
      """.trimIndent()
    )
  }

  enum class Response {
    HIGHER, LOWER, CORRECT, UNKNOWN
  }
}

fun main(args:Array<String>) {
  Guesser()
}
```

Note: I'm also learning the language and I could be wrong with some things so, the above code can be improved and is not free of mistakes and non-idiomatic constructs.

Comment: You should explain why your version is better than the op's one.

Comment: @denis: I included several comments in the code with that purpose.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  Given that we have a format that allows the intermixing of code and text, it is often better to put explanations in text.  Only put explanations in code comments if you would naturally comment there in the program.  For example, `/* If you're going to reassign the members, they must be `var` */` is probably *not* something that you'd normally put in real code.  By contrast, `Assume error if this is reached` is a perfectly natural comment.

Comment: @mdfst13 I see. Thanks. I will edit my answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Kotlin `when` on enum is recommended to be exhaustive but does not have to be.

Comment: `parseResponse` can be a single `when` expression as well. e.g. `fun parseResponse(response: String?) = when (response?.toLowerCase()) { null -> Response.UNKNOWN "higher", "h" -> Response.HIGHER "lower", "l" -> Response.LOWER "yes", "y" -> Response.CORRECT else -> Response.UNKNOWN }`

Comment: `trimIndent()` can be used instead of `trimMargin()`; using `trimIndent` avoids the need for a prefix.

Comment: Really good feedback, thank you. Updated version: https://github.com/JNBarnes/LearningKotlin/blob/master/src/challenges/difficult/GuessingGame.kt
I also made better use of when statements amongst a few other minor improvements.

Comment: Don't think it is correct to increment `turnCount` when `Response.UNKNOWN`.

Comment: Also, in `Guesser` constructor, `range` is not a property. Given the way `range` is used in the initialization,  it is more straightforward to define the constructor as: `Guesser(var lowerLimit: Int = 1, var upperLimit: Int = 100)`